# What can people do about Tor's weaknesses?

Tags: privacy, tor

I read [Tor's Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tor_%28anonymity_network%29) and found out it has 12 [weaknesses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tor_(anonymity_network)#Weaknesses). What can people or The Tor Project do about those weaknesses? If they don't anything about it, wouldn't it compromise Tor users' anonymity?

Comment: Some of those weaknesses might be mitigated with something like Whonix (see https://www.whonix.org/wiki/Comparison_with_Others), others might be mitigated with good OPSEC, others might be too difficult to exploit in practice, others might actually be worrying but I bet researchers are working on them.

Answer (score 1):

No anonymizing service is foolproof. To prevent yourself from being deanonymized by the abuse of tor weaknesses you should do the following:

Maintain good OPSEC.

Use security focused OS like tails or whonix.

Finally chain multiple anonymizing services over relying on just one service like tor alone.

Comment: `Finally chain multiple anonymizing services over relying on just one service like tor alone.`

Could you please give an example?

Comment: Yes lots of them out there JonDo into Tor, VPN into Tor, VPN into VPN into Tor, SSH into Tor. Other variants can be Tor into VPN, VPN into Tor into JonDo you can get creative with all of these.